# How can I reduce the number of conditions in a statement?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

In this exercise I need to come up with a way to find the least common multiple (LCM) for the first 20 natural numbers (1-20).
So far this is what I got:

```
if exercise == 34:
    lcm = 20
    while lcm % 2 != 0 or \
            lcm % 3 != 0 or \
            lcm % 4 != 0 or \
            lcm % 5 != 0 or \
            lcm % 6 != 0 or \
            lcm % 7 != 0 or \
            lcm % 8 != 0 or \
            lcm % 9 != 0 or \
            lcm % 10 != 0 or \
            lcm % 11 != 0 or \
            lcm % 12 != 0 or \
            lcm % 13 != 0 or \
            lcm % 14 != 0 or \
            lcm % 15 != 0 or \
            lcm % 16 != 0 or \
            lcm % 17 != 0 or \
            lcm % 18 != 0 or \
            lcm % 19 != 0 or \
            lcm % 20 != 0:
        lcm += 1
    print(lcm)
```

Is there a more efficient, to code this without the need to write a condition for every potential number to be factored in the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say best way [will be](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/math.html#math.lcm) this:

```
>>> math.lcm(*range(1, 21))
232792560
```

As the result is fairly large, your `+= 1` loop will take quite long no matter how nice others make it.

Best way before Python 3.9 might be something like this:

```
>>> def lcm(a, b):
        return a * b // math.gcd(a, b)

>>> functools.reduce(lcm, range(1, 21))
232792560
```

Both ways take only a few microseconds.

Or... with a little bit of head work, you could just multiply the largest powers of all primes in that range:

```
>>> 16*9*5*7*11*13*17*19
232792560
```

Comment: Will this new Python 3.9 function preserve the short circuiting of the algorithm?

Comment: @Milky Not sure what you mean. That question doesn't really make sense. What would it short circuit?

Comment: I mean if will it stop iterating as soon as it finds the LCM?

Comment: @Milky What do you mean with iterating? Like yours? It doesn't do that. It would be really bad for a library function to use such a terrible method.

Comment: Sorry, I might have confused myself with the other answers, I'll check the documentation to see how this new function works

Comment: @Milky It does pretty much the same as my second solution. It's not in the documentation, you'll have to look at the source code.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a shorter version, replace long `or` with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
if excercise == 34:
    lcm = 20
    while any(lcm % i != 0 for i in range(2, 21)):
        lcm += 1
    print(lcm)
```

Comment: The nice thing is that this preserves the short circuiting of the original expression.

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong but this code seems to be in an infinite loop, although it worked with smaller intervals

Comment: @Milky Well I guess you can say it **seems** to be in an infinite loop. Of course it'll finish eventually, but as I said in my answer, this "will take quite long".